# Mac OSX Sierra, Out of the blue, User logs into the domain, and everything in the account is gone

Tags: active-directory, mac-osx, domain-controller, microsoft, deploystudio

Never have seen this before, but just had a user log into his domain account, and it's like he is logging into his account for the first time? This user has been logging in for months now with no problem. Usually when this happens, it creates a separate folder in the Users directory, but this time nothing. It's a pretty standard setup with AD/mobile accts logging into the domain with OS X. Just wondering if anyone has seen this and maybe point me where to start to look? Is it a mobile account glitch? These clients are being synced with Munki/Deploy Studio as well, could they be the culprits?

Comment: I'm confused about what exactly is normally there that is now gone. To me an "account" in AD is an active directory object that has a lot of attributes, that Microsoft calls a "User". So my first thought is that "everything in the account is gone" means that somehow the AD user got messed up, but I'm pretty sure that's not what you mean. More likely you are saying some files are missing, but what files, and where would those files be if they weren't missing? On a server? Local folder? Somewhere else?

Comment: Ohhhhhh sorry, I should have been more specific. Everything is gone meant, all his files, preferences for programs etc etc. All the files in his Documents folder, Downloads Folder, Desktop, and all the setting in the user's Library Folder. It's like a new account has been created and the user is starting fresh, with no trace of his old files or settings files. And we can't find the old files anywhere....